# knitr and UTF8 encoding

Tags: r, latex, knitr

A few days ago, I started writing on a german R-Script. Unfortunately, the following code chunk doesn't work when I `knit()` the document:

```
@    
<<>>=
äö <- ordered(c(1,3,2,2))
@
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

PS: I'm working with Linux.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using Linux, things should be easy. It is probably just a LaTeX problem; most importantly, did you specify the encoding of your document? e.g. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. This works for me under Ubuntu.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
äö <- ordered(c(1,3,2,2))
@

\end{document}
```

BTW, perhaps it is not a good idea to use non-ASCII characters in R object names, although they also work.

Comment: Yes, I specified the encoding but nonetheless it doesn't work. It says: "Unable to parse R-code ..."  

Regarding non-ASCII characters in object names: I just used it as an example. More often, it concerns colnames in data frames that contain an "ä" or "ö" for example.

Comment: I see. This seems to be a problem of the `parser` package (or my bug).  You can try to `update.packages()` and `remove.packages(c('parser', 'highlight'))`. Since v0.6.3, `knitr` no longer has to depend on `parser` or `highlight` (https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS#L48).

Comment: Thank you. I updated knitr to 0.6.3 and now everything's fine.