# R Wrong encoding in Rstudio console (but ok in R GUI and ggplot2)

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio

I'm on Windows 8.1 (en) and my R console won't understand Russian characters and produce smth like this (both in console and if I run R file)

```
> x <- "Привет"
> print(x)
[1] "Ïðèâåò"
```

I know that this can happen if you save CP1251 as CP1252. I set up all R options to UTF-8, and  source files as UTF-8, but this doesn't help. I also set up sysLocale to Russian as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031630/how-to-source-r-file-saved-using-utf-8-encoding), but got nothing. Some advise from [RStudio faq](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/encoding) didn't help either. The strange thing though, that ggplot2 works absolutely fine

```
dt <- as.data.frame(cbind(x = c("Один", "Два"), y = c(3, 5)))
ggplot(dt, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_bar() + xlab("Счет")
```

This is my sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

I use last version of RStudio, but dev version also would not help

**UPDATE**:

```
> Encoding(x)
[1] "unknown"
> getOption("encoding")
[1] "native.enc"
```

If I use RGUI, after `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Russian")` it will allow to

```
> print(x)
[1] "Привет"
```

I also checked in the Russian version of Windows - Rstudio works ok

Comment: It would not be a great problem, but I generate knitr reports in Russian and everything becomes screwed up

Comment: Is it a LaTeX problem? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11217621/322912

Comment: this sounds like a good question for the RStudio forums ...

Comment: Will repost there tomorrow, thank you for an idea.
It's not at Latex problem - console didn't work either
I guess it is more Windows problem(

Comment: What are `Encoding(x)` and `getOption("encoding")`, and does the problem work if you use R GUI?

Comment: @RichieCotton Encoding gives nothing, R GUI works fine, when I switch encoding to Russian. Seems like RStudio problem...

Comment: Can you try the following in your RStudio console: `intToUtf8(seq(1072,,1,30),multiple=T)`

Comment: @krlmlr Works fine, it prints Russian alphabet (even if print it after saving to variable)

Answer (score 4):

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Russian")
```

Did not work for me.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_RU.UTF-8")
```

Did the job! now utf files with Cyrillic characters display properly in the R/RStudio Console.
But that only seems to work until R or RStudio is restarted.

also, running

```
defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

in OS X Terminal solves all my problems with non-Latin characters for good.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Russian_Russia.1252")
```

fixed the problem in my case.