# R rstudio view encoding different than print

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio

When I use non-standard letters, the Rstudio view function tends to use a different encoding than print. If you run the following code you will see the difference. I've tried setting all possible encodings, but View keeps displaying them wrongly. Any solutions?

```
x <- data.frame(test=c('a','b','c','d','é'))
View(x)
print(x)
```

I will upload an image as soon as I have more reputation.

Comment: Encoding is a bitsue in R. See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900668/r-wrong-encoding-in-rstudio-console-but-ok-in-r-gui-and-ggplot2 helps.

Comment: What version of RStudio are you using? The latest release, 0.99, has a revamped viewer that pays more attention to character encodings.

Comment: Ok, took me a while, but finally installed the newest version and that seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved in the newest version of Rstudio (1.0.136).